# Read latest records from Kafka using pyspark batch job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am executing a batch job in pyspark, where spark will read data from  kafka topic for every 5 min.

```
df = spark \
  .read \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1") \
  .option("subscribePattern", "test") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .option("endingOffsets", "latest") \
  .load()
```

Whenever spark reads data from kafka it is reading all the data including previous batches.
I want to read data for the current batch  or latest records which is not read before.
Please suggest !! Thank you.

Comment: how did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 1):

From https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries

> For batch queries, latest (either implicitly or by using -1 in json)
>   is not allowed.

Using earliest means all the data again is obtained.

You will need to define the offset explicitly every time you run like, e.g.:

```
.option("startingOffsets", """{"topic1":{"0":23,"1":-2},"topic2":{"0":-2}}""")
```

That implies you need to save the offsets processed per partition. I am looking into this in the near future myself for a project. Some items hereunder items to help:

https://medium.com/datakaresolutions/structured-streaming-kafka-integration-6ab1b6a56dd1 stating what you observe:

> Create a Kafka Batch Query
>
> - Spark also provides a feature to fetch the
>     data from Kafka in batch mode. In batch mode Spark will consume all
>     the messages at once. Kafka in batch mode requires two important
>     parameters Starting offsets and ending offsets, if not specified spark
>     will consider the default configuration which is,
>
>   - startingOffsets — earliest
>   - endingOffsets — latest

https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-gt-hdfss3-batch-ingestion-through-spark  alludes as well to what you should do, with the following:

> 8. And, finally, save these Kafka topic endOffsets to file system – local or HDFS (or commit them to ZooKeeper). This will be used for the
>      next run of starting the offset for a Kafka topic. Here we are making
>      sure the job's next run will read from the offset where the previous
>      run left off.

This blog https://dataengi.com/2019/06/06/spark-structured-streaming/  I think has the answer for saving offsets.

Comment: Having to store offsets myself seems like hard work, when normally Kafka does a great job of it. This answer is now nearly four years old, I wonder if Spark now has a better solution?

Comment: works using structured streaming without batching in 3.5.0 - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77688525/problem-with-kafka-offsets-in-apache-spark-3-5-structured-streaming-in-batch-mod

Comment: @AntKutschera not sure what yr point is. Batch kafka has more capabilities.