# Problem with Kafka offsets in Apache Spark 3.5 structured streaming in Batch Mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am writing a batch query which uses Kafka as a source, according to the [Kafka integration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries) and want to submit this batch periodically, say once a day, to process records which have been added since the last run. During testing while running `pyspark` I notice that every time the batch runs, it reads all the records, not just the ones that have been added since the last run. My code is approximately as follows.

The question is: what do I have to change, so that each time it runs, I only process new Kafka records?

```
builder = (pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp")
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
            .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
            .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", s3a_access_key)
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", s3a_secret_key)
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", s3a_host_port)
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false")
            .config("spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled", "false")
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
            .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/data/custom-log4j.properties")
           )

my_packages = [
                   # "io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.0.0", -> no need, since configure_spark_with_delta_pip below adds it
                   "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4",
                   "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client-runtime:3.3.4",
                   "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client-api:3.3.4",
                   "io.delta:delta-contribs_2.12:3.0.0",
                   "io.delta:delta-hive_2.12:3.0.0",
                   "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.12.603",
                   "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.0",
               ]

# Create a Spark instance with the builder
# As a result, you now can read and write Delta tables
spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder, extra_packages=my_packages).getOrCreate()


kdf = (spark
        .read
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers)
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", kafka_security_protocol)
        .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256")
        .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", f"org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"{kafka_username}\" password=\"{kafka_password}\";")
        .option("includeHeaders", "true")
        .option("subscribe", "filebeat")
        .option("checkpointLocation", "s3a://checkpointlocation/")
        .load())

kdf = kdf.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "headers", "CAST(topic AS STRING)", "CAST(partition AS STRING)", "CAST(offset AS STRING)")

out = kdf...

(out.select(["message", "partition", "offset"])
                     .show(
                        truncate=False,
                        n=MAX_JAVA_INT
                    ))


spark.stop()
```

This outputs a table where I can see that the same offsets are being processed with each run.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is related to not actually submitting the job to a cluster, rather running it with "master("local[*]")"? I also wonder where Spark stores the committed offsets or if it logs them at trace level, so that I could take a peak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the topic in batch mode [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries) which sets `startingOffsets = earliest` by default. Also the `checkpointLocation` has no effect in batch mode, you have to read in streaming mode `spark.readStream...` and the processed offsets will be stored there.

Example Application:

```
source_df = (
    spark
    .readStream
    .format('kafka')
    .options(**{
        'subscribe': 'some_topic',
        'startingOffsets': 'earliest',
    })
    .load()
)
writer = (
    source_df
    .writeStream
    .format('parquet')
    .option('path', '/some_path')
    .outputMode('append')
    .option('checkpointLocation', '<some-location>')
    .trigger(availableNow=True)
)

streaming_query = writer.start()
streaming_query.awaitTermination()
spark.stop()
```

First iteration of application:

1. The `checkpointLocation` is empty, so Spark will read from earliest offsets until the current offsets.
2. The reached offsets will be stored in the `checkpointLocation`
3. The applications stops.

Second iteration of application

1. The `checkpointLocation` is not empty, so Spark will start reading from the offsets there until the current offsets.
2. The reached offsets will be stored in `checkpointLocation`.
3. The applications stops.

Note that `.option('checkpointLocation', '<some-location>')` has to be called on the DataStreamWriter, NOT on the DataStreamReader.

Comment: When I set startingOffsets to earliest, it will consume all records from the earliest offset, every time I start the batch. But I want to consume only those records which have not yet been processed. The other problem with readStream is that the stream won't finish, and the job will run forever. Although I can set "once" or "availableNow", but they just return either everything, or an empty batch if I use "latest" as the startingOffsets.  So I don't think this solution fulfils my non-functional requirement to run as a batch?

Comment: ok, i was splitting the dataframes into two streams using filter, and hadn't set both to use only available and to do checkpointing - it works now - many thanks!